# Prewitt filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gradient

I am trying to take a gradient of an image using the Prewitt filter. Can you tell me if this approach is correct?

I = imread('image.jpg')
Gx = [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1];
Gy = [1 1 1; 0 0 0; 1 1 1];
D = conv2(conv2(I, Gx), Gy)
imshow(D)

Is that correct? Is there a cleaner way to do it (no need to call conv2 twice)? Is conv2(I, Gx) the same as conv2(Gx, I)? (i.e. commutative?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by my wikipedia-ing it looks like what you should do is:

```
I = imread('image.jpg')
Gx = [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1];
Gy = [1 1 1; 0 0 0; -1 -1 -1];

A = sqrt( conv2(I,Gx).^2 + conv2(I,Gy).^2 );
imshow(A);
```

[Link to Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator)